# How can I detect button press from remote BLE clicker on linux?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use a logitech clicker using bluetooth (BLE) on a raspberry-like linux device, for specific applications. My goal is to be able to detect when a button is pressed on the remote controller and then use this information in my application code.
A perfect solution would be to have a device file containing buttons state information.

I connected the remote controller using `bluetoothctl`. I am then clueless on how to get the information of the button press.
I tried to sniff bluetooth packets using `hcidump` but this is not giving me any results.
I also cannot figure out how to link the remote controller to a device file.
I have the following information on the device from `bluetoothctl`:

```
[Logi R500]# info
Device C3:6F:57:12:7B:01 (random)
        Name: Logi R500
        Alias: Logi R500
        Appearance: 0x03c0
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d)
        Modalias: usb:v046DpB505d0008
```

Would you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Is it acting as a HID device or does it use a custom GATT service? You can use btmon instead of the deprecated hcidump to sniff packets.

Comment: I added some info about the device. It seems like it has a HID but I don't really know how to access its values.

Comment: If your Raspberry Pi like device has a desktop, it should just be to pair the device in the Bluetooth settings and it will act like a keyboard, and then just start listening to keyboard events as usual in your application.